# Dissable a button on the screen - Android Studio

Tags: android, listview, button

I hope youre doing well

I have some buttons with onClick events on it. But I also display a ListView and on the buttons zone the listview items can be "touch". So when the listview is display the buttons not only have to be invisible (using button_name.setAlpha(0)) but also they must be dissable. Can that be done?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using alpha, you should be using the visibility property of the button.

```
button_name.setVisibilty(View.INVISIBLE)
```

or

```
button_name.setVisibilty(View.GONE)
```

If you want to disable a button you can use

```
button_name.setEnabled(false)
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

hope this helps,

To enable button -

```
button.setClickable(true);
```

To disable button -

```
button.setClickable(false);
```